# swift function does not work, help someone figure it out?

Tags: swift, function

```
func Function(_ currency: Currency, _ amount: Int) -> String {
    func unsignInt( amou: Int) -> String {
            
            return String(-amou)
        }
        
        let curArray = [
            ".rub": " ₽;",
            ".eur": " €;",
            ".usd": " $;"
        ]
        
        var amountRes = ""
        amount < 0  ? (amountRes = "(" + unsignInt(amou: amount) + ")") : (amountRes = String(amount))
        
        for (curCode, prnCode) in curArray{
            if curCode as AnyObject === currency as AnyObject {
                return amountRes + prnCode
            }
        }
        return "0"
    }
```

This function accepts a currency in the form of Currency and an integer amount.
It should return a string containing the amount and currency symbol. Negative numbers must be displayed in parentheses and without a minus sign.
But this function does not work, help someone figure it out

Comment: **What** does not work? And what is `Currency`? Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you please add here what value you are passing?

Comment: Why do you call a dictionary of currencies “curArray”?

Comment: Your curArray is not an array but a dictionary and casting to AnyObject is just bad and casting two objects of different types to AnyObject to compare if they are the same object (triple =) will never return true.

Comment: How you set amountRes is more than ugly. === for AnyObject will just compare the references in your case, so how is that supposed to work? “unsignInt” and “amou” are just awful names.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is strange. I would write is more like this:

```
func amount(_ currency: Currency, _ amount: Int) -> String {
    
    let currancyDict = [
        ".rub": " ₽;",
        ".eur": " €;",
        ".usd": " $;"
    ]
    
    let amountString: String
    if amount < 0 {
      amountString = "(\(abs(amount)))"
    } else {
      amountString = "\(amount)"
    }

    if let abbreviation = currancyDict[currency.string] {
      return amountString + abbreviation
    } else {
      return "0"
    }
}
```

To make that work, you need to implement a calculated property `string` on your `Currency` type that returns the string as it is used in the keys of the `currencyDict`.

I would even put the `currencyDict` into the `Currency` type and add a method to the `Currency` type that takes an amount integer and returns the string.